# Uninstall virtualenv which was installed through sudo pip

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python

***********Update2******************

Tried and successfully created a virtual environment using virtualenv.

```
[08:05 USER@system ~] > mkdir test_virtual
[08:05 USER@system ~] > virtualenv test_virtual/
New python executable in /home/USER/test_virtual/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[08:05 USER@system ~] > ls test_virtual/
bin  include  lib  local  pip-selfcheck.json
```

***********Update1******************

As requested here are the pastebin links to [pip list](http://pastebin.com/JAE9GdJ9) and [pip3 list](http://pastebin.com/NwJechir).

***********Original******************

I installed virtualenv using sudo pip install virtualenv, which after reading on several answers here is actually not a good practice. When I try to uninstall it (mainly because I'm planning to go the anaconda way and I don't like extra dirt that I don't use on my system) I get the following error:

```
(09:20 USER@system ~) > sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
The directory '/home/USER/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Cannot uninstall requirement virtualenv, not installed
The directory '/home/USER/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
Please check the permissions and owner of that directory.
If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

When I use `sudo -H` flag, I get this:

```
Cannot uninstall requirement virtualenv, not installed
```

But I confirmed that virtualenv is still installed:

```
(09:25 USER@system ~) > which virtualenv
virtualenv is /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
virtualenv is /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
virtualenv is /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
virtualenv is /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
```

How do I uninstall virtualenv from my system?

Thanks.

Comment: I've removed them.

Comment: Are you sure you installed `virtualenv` using `sudo pip install virtualenv` instead of `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`? Can you do `sudo pip list` and `sudo pip3 list`?

Comment: I did those commands. They spit out a bunch of package names and at the end of the list the same error that says "the directory /home/USER/.cache/pip/http or its parent directory..." was also displayed for both pip and pip3. Also when I grep'd the list for virtualenv (using both virtual as the pattern and env as a the pattern) I didn't get any output except the error.

Comment: Can you put those outputs into your question or put them into a pastebin and link the pastebin? We are going to need more information than what you have given so far to figure out what happened.

Comment: Hmm, so `pip list` and `pip3 list` don't have `virtualenv`, which is at least consistent with the "Cannot uninstall requirement virtualenv, not installed" error message. If you just try to run `virtualenv`, are you able to create virtual environments?

Comment: Yes. I've updated my question with the results.

Comment: @shaun How did you solve this? I too have installed virtualenv `pip install virtualenv` and now I cannot remove it. Also virtualenv does not show up in `pip freeze` or `pip list`. How did you uninstall virtualenv?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the same thing and I saw this by chance. you can do this.

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualenv  
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove virtualenv
```

If it is normal, the following statement is not executed. But try it once.

```
sudo apt-get purge python-virtualenv  
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 3):

try `sudo pip remove virtualenv` and this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt remove python3-venv
```

.
.
.
This is the command, which really gonna work on that !