# Unable to uninstall virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: software-uninstall, virtualenv

```
$ sudo pip uninstall virtualenv 
WARNING: Skipping virtualenv as it is not installed.
```

```
$ sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenv 
WARNING: Skipping virtualenv as it is not installed.
```

```
$ sudo apt-get purge python-virtualenv  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python-virtualenv' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 136 not upgraded.
```

```
$ virtualenv --version
virtualenv 20.4.3 from /home/manu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/__init__.py
```

`pip list` and `pip3 list` mention the `virtualenv`.

Also, commands [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/a/932870) do not work:

> ```
> sudo apt-get remove virtualenv  
> sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove virtualenv
> ```

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge python-virtualenv  
> sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-virtualenv
> ```

Comment: @user535733 upgraded, ran the upgrade command, from 136 its now 1 not upgraded.

Comment: @guiverc I have updated my heading. The command mentioned are taken from the link. please read and dont be in a hurry to reply

Comment: Your title mentioned a *snap* only release, but the following lines referred to `apt-get` commands which applied to a different product.  If details are incorrect, I see little reason going further as mixing two different products shows a lack of precision, or lack of attention to detail (and I don't know what other errors were provided...)

Comment: Hello @guiverc . Leave that command, i am not using it. Was just mentioning it.
Would you please guide me with uninstalling virtualenv. Its an OS Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS,  64 bit.

Comment: You are asking how to "uninstall" something that was seemingly not installed using either apt nor pip. How you install something depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. If you installed it using apt or pip, then there was an error during uninstall that you didn't show us. If you installed using some other method, then knowing the method matters.

Comment: I do remember using "pip install virtualenv".
contents in virtualenv directory: 
activation  app_data  config  create  discovery  info.py  __init__.py  __main__.py  __pycache__  report.py  run  seed  util  version.py

Comment: Try `python -m pip uninstall --user virtualenv`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema 
Usage:   
  /usr/bin/python -m pip uninstall [options] <package> ...
  /usr/bin/python -m pip uninstall [options] -r <requirements file> ...

no such option: --user

Comment: @ManuGupta Try `pip3`, or without the `--user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your venv location: `/home/manu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/init.py`. The `.local` directory means that it didn't come from a deb or Snap package. Maybe from pip. Maybe from some other method.

The `python3.8` directory tells you which version of Python uses it, so your commands should be `python3` and `pip3` -- Py2-specific commands won't help.

Since you queried pip3, and it never heard of `virtualenv`, seems safe enough to delete that directory.

Comment: So you are suggesting to remove the directory name 'virtualenv'?

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved like this, take a look at the attached PrintScreen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye5JL.png)

Comment: Text is preferred to images here: lighter and easier to copy/paste.